# ActiveRecord validations for modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have validations within each of my models. I also have a module defined in my lib folder with methods that update my my models. How do I get the validations I have defined in my models to work for the methods in my module.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    unless MYLIB::isthisgood(record.name)
      record.errors[:base] << "Name is No Good"
    end
  end
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```